# Equivalent definition of Markov process from Shreve

Tags: finance, markov-process

In the book "Stochastic calculus for finance-II" [http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~matheming/Steven%20E.%20Shreve-Stochastic%20Calculus%20for%20Finance%20II.pdf](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ematheming/Steven%20E.%20Shreve-Stochastic%20Calculus%20for%20Finance%20II.pdf) , the author mentions two definitions of Markov process as equivalent in equations 2.3.29 and 2.3.30 (page 74 and 75). The equations are -

1. $$\mathbb{E}[f(X(t))|\mathcal{F}(s)] = g(X(s))$$

2)$$\mathbb{E}[f(t, X(t))|\mathcal{F}(s)] = f(s, X(s))$$

under the usual conditions(please see link for details). Can someone show me how to get 2) from 1) ?

Comment: Remark 2.3.7 is the explanation: "(we do not need different symbols f and g because the time variables t and s indicate we are dealing with different functions of x at the different times)"

If you look closely at the definition on 2.3.6. there is a time-dependency, because the equation should hold for $0\geq s\geq t \geq  T$.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. Thanks!